# Computer Boots to Grub after removing Lubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, windows-8

Recently I tried removing Lubuntu in dual boot mode with Windows 8.1. However, I probably made an error because I tried to remove the Lubuntu partition from the Windows Disk Management interface. Now I am stuck with the grub command line when I start my computer. I have a laptop so windows was pre-installed on it. How can I boot into Windows and not grub now that I have made this mess?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to boot to a windows disc or flash drive and select a recovery option. (There's an option to repair boot problems)

Comment: I don't get the option from the flash drive, when I open my computer, it just goes to the grub command line

Comment: There may be a key combination you have to hold or you may have to change your boot order in your bios.

Comment: How do you access the bios from grub?

Comment: Your computer skips the BIOS and alternative boot options in favor of the grub screen?

Comment: Yes, theres no alternatives when I bring my computer on. It's an Asus G75V.

Comment: Ok nvm, I found the way to do it. Apparently you just have hold the F2 button while pressing the power button

Comment: Sweet! Well, hopefully you can boot to your Windows recovery now!